# How to subscribe for a topic and receive packets from server using websocket flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, socket.io

I have code in the server that sends data and I need to subscribe to the topic that the server has and then I need to get data packets from the server. I have no idea how to subscribe to the topic and get data in flutter. please help in subscribing topic and getting data from the server using WebSocket flutter.

Comment: Fortunately, Flutter’s language, Dart, provides you with an out-of-box solution for dealing with WebSockets: the WebSocket class. So have a look at the documentation or search for a tutorial

Comment: How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)